# Statistics with Magick++ ImageMagick 7.0.5-4 Q16 x86_64 issue

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I'm trying to get minima in image with Magick++ API version 7:

```
img.type(Magick::GrayscaleType);

auto stats = img.statistics();

std::cout << argv[0] << ":" << stats.channel(Magick::PixelChannel::GrayPixelChannel ).minima() << std::endl;

img.write("test" + Glib::ustring(argv[0]) + ".bmp");
```

For several images I get the same `minima` value and a wrong value > 1.0.
Running `identify -verbose` on written image gives me correct value.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT 1**

If I do

```
img.read("test" + Glib::ustring(argv[0]) + ".bmp");
stats = img.statistics();
std::cout << argv[0] << ":" << stats.channel(Magick::PixelChannel::GrayPixelChannel ).minima() << std::endl;
```

I get the correct value for minima (and it is not in range 0 - 1.0 in ImageMagick 7).

img here is the result of

```
img.composite(mask, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp);
```

where mask is

```
Magick::Image newmask(Magick::Geometry(width,height),Magick::Color("white"));
    newmask.strokeColor("black");
    newmask.fillColor("black");
    newmask.draw( Magick::DrawableCircle(xc,yc, xc,yc+rc-10) );
    newmask.transparent(Magick::Color("black"));
    newmask.depth(8);
    mask = newmask;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember you are working with Quantum values -- which differ between system installs.

Use either `value/QuantumRange` or `value*QuantumScale` to calculate the display value between `0` & `1.0`.

```cpp
stats.channel(Magick::PixelChannel::GrayPixelChannel).minima()/QuantumRange
```

For example...

```cpp
// sample_program.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    InitializeMagick(argv[0]);
    Image img("rose:");
    img.type(GrayscaleType);
    auto stats = img.statistics();
    cout << stats.channel(PixelChannel::GrayPixelChannel).minima()/QuantumRange << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile & execute...

```
 $ ./sample_program
 => 0.14478
```

Compare with CLI application

```
 $ convert rose: -type GrayScale -format '%[fx:minima]\n' info:
 => 0.144778
```

Slight rounding, but that's expected with `std:cout`.

Comment: Why is different of : `convert rose: -colorspace Gray bmp:- | identify -verbose - | grep min`
      min: 37 (0.145098)

Comment: Because the data population is different. Each time you manipulate an image in memory, or by encoding, the statistic values will alter. In your comment's example, you generate a BMP 8-bit sRGB image, and have observed some precision loss.